# start activity for result gets null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-activity

I put speech function into a new class called voiceAssistants, however, when i start it, it always give me an null pointer exception error.

voice Assistants:

```
public class VoiceAssistants {
    private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static VoiceActivityHelper voiceAssistants;
    public VoiceAssistants(){
        voiceAssistants = new VoiceActivityHelper();
    }
    /**
     * Start voice input
     */
    public void starVoiceAssistants(){
        this.voiceAssistants.startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
    }

    private static class VoiceActivityHelper extends Activity {

        private static ArrayList<String> matches;

        public ArrayList<String> getResultSet(){
            return matches;
        }

        private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, String.format(
                "%s_%s", Locale.getDefault().getLanguage(), Locale
                        .getDefault().getCountry()));
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                "Speech recognition demo");
                        //error happen here!!!
            startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I put it into normal activity that generated by new project, it won't tall any error.
log infos:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(22769): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(22769):
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
E/AndroidRuntime(22769):    
at panda.com.db.VoiceAssistants$VoiceActivityHelper.startVoiceRecognitionActivity(VoiceAssistants.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(22769):    
at panda.com.db.VoiceAssistants$VoiceActivityHelper.access$1(VoiceAssistants.java:47)
E/AndroidRuntime(22769):    
at panda.com.db.VoiceAssistants.starVoiceAssistants(VoiceAssistants.java:24)
```

plz help, thank you!!

Comment: You can't work with activity like this: voiceAssistants = new VoiceActivityHelper();

Comment: Can you post the full code of `startVoiceRecognitionActivity`?

Comment: Can you show us what `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH` is? 

Also make sure that you have that activity class properly defined in your android manifest?

Comment: I have posted the full version of startVoiceRecongnitionActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `startActivityForResult()` but this isn't an `Activity`.  Your `Activity` is a private inner class that no one else has access to.

Comment: so i need to change it to public?

Comment: Yes and you'll need to declare it in your Manifest.